# Rocky Linux/Centos 8: Why are we unable to switch to a virtual terminal if in X?

Tags: linux-terminal, centos-8

We are unable to switch from X to a virtual terminal on Rocky Linux. `xmodmap -pke` and `dumpkeys` results are the same as CentOS 7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> on Rocky (below) has no effect. `chvt` works. Switching between virtual terminals works as expected. We tried a different keyboard.

`xev` on CentOS 7 also shows a `VisibilityNotify` event (after <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and the KeyRelease is for <kbd>F6</kbd> - not XF86Switch_VT_6.

`xev` on Rocky Linux:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x17e, subw 0x0, time 3843595, (195,941), root:(1265,972),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x17e, subw 0x0, time 3843627, (195,941), root:(1265,972),
    state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x17e, subw 0x0, time 3845130, (195,941), root:(1265,972),
    state 0xc, keycode 72 (keysym 0x1008fe06, XF86Switch_VT_6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x17e, subw 0x0, time 3846507, (195,941), root:(1265,972),
    state 0xc, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x17e, subw 0x0, time 3846555, (195,941), root:(1265,972),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False*
```

Answer (score 0):

We installed a newer release of Rocky Linux and the problem disappeared. I think it was Rocky-8.4-x86_64 to Rocky-8.5-x86_64.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good point - I revised it. Thanks